# How to manage the ownership of a file held within a struct in Rust?

Tags: io, rust

Is there a good way to handle the ownership of a file held within a struct using Rust?  As a stripped down example, consider:

```
// Buffered file IO
use std::io::{BufReader,BufRead};
use std::fs::File;            

// Structure that contains a file
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {                
    file : BufReader <File>,
    data : Vec <f64>,   
}   

// Reads the file and strips the header    
fn init_foo(fname : &str) -> Foo {   

    // Open the file                                      
    let mut file = BufReader::new(File::open(fname).unwrap());

    // Dump the header     
    let mut header = String::new();
    let _ = file.read_line(&mut header);

    // Return our foo
    Foo { file : file, data : Vec::new() }          
}   

// Read the remaining foo data and process it
fn read_foo(mut foo : Foo) -> Foo {

    // Strip one more line
    let mut header_alt = String::new();
    let _ = foo.file.read_line(&mut header_alt);

    // Read in the rest of the file line by line
    let mut data = Vec::new();         
    for (lineno,line) in foo.file.lines().enumerate() {

        // Strip the error
        let line = line.unwrap();

        // Print some diagnostic information    
        println!("Line {}: val {}",lineno,line);

        // Save the element
        data.push(line.parse::<f64>().unwrap());
    }   

    // Export foo
    Foo { data : data, ..foo}
}   

fn main() {

    // Initialize our foo
    let foo = init_foo("foo.txt");

    // Read in our data
    let foo = read_foo(foo); 

    // Print out some debugging info
    println!("{:?}",foo); 
}
```

This currently gives the compilation error:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `foo.file`
  --> src/main.rs:48:5
   |
35 |     for (lineno,line) in foo.file.lines().enumerate() {
   |                          -------- value moved here
...
48 |     Foo { data : data, ..foo}
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `foo.file` has type `std::io::BufReader<std::fs::File>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
error: Could not compile `rust_file_struct`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

And, to be sure, this makes sense.  Here, `lines()` takes ownership of the buffered file, so we can't use the value in the return.  What's confusing me is a better way to handle this situation.  Certainly, after the for loop, the file is consumed, so it really can't be used.  To better denote this, we could represent file as `Option <BufReader <File>>`.  However, this causes some grief because the second `read_line` call, inside of `read_foo`, needs a mutable reference to `file` and I'm not sure how to obtain one it it's wrapped inside of an `Option`.  Is there a good way of handling the ownership?

To be clear, this is a stripped down example.  In the actual use case, there are several files as well as other data.  I've things structured in this way because it represents a configuration that comes from the command line options.  Some of the options are files, some are flags.  In either case, I'd like to do some processing, but not all, of the files early in order to throw the appropriate errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on track with using the `Option` within the `Foo` struct. Assuming the struct becomes:

```
struct Foo {                
    file : Option<BufReader <File>>,
    data : Vec <f64>,   
}
```

The following code is a possible solution:

```
// Reads the file and strips the header    
fn init_foo(fname : &str) -> Foo {   

    // Open the file                                      
    let mut file = BufReader::new(File::open(fname).unwrap());

    // Dump the header     
    let mut header = String::new();
    let _ = file.read_line(&mut header);

    // Return our foo
    Foo { file : Some(file), data : Vec::new() }          
}   

// Read the remaining foo data and process it
fn read_foo(foo : Foo) -> Option<Foo> {

    let mut file = foo.file?;

    // Strip one more line
    let mut header_alt = String::new();
    let _ = file.read_line(&mut header_alt);

    // Read in the rest of the file line by line
    let mut data = Vec::new();         
    for (lineno,line) in file.lines().enumerate() {

        // Strip the error
        let line = line.unwrap();

        // Print some diagnostic information    
        println!("Line {}: val {}",lineno,line);

        // Save the element
        data.push(line.parse::<f64>().unwrap());
    }   

    // Export foo
    Some(Foo { data : data, file: None})
}
```

Note in this case that `read_foo` returns an optional `Foo` due to the fact that the `file` could be `None`.

On a side note, IMO, unless you absolutely need the `BufReader` to be *travelling* along with the `Foo`, I would discard it. As you've already found, calling `lines` causes a move, which makes it difficult to retain within another struct. As a suggestion, you could make the `file` field simply a `String` so that you could always derive the `BufReader` and read the file when needed.

For example, here's a solution where a file name (i.e. a &str) can be turned into a `Foo` with all the line processing done just before the construction of the struct.

```
// Buffered file IO
use std::io::{BufReader,BufRead};
use std::fs::File;            

// Structure that contains a file
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {                
    file : String,
    data : Vec <f64>,   
}   

trait IntoFoo {
    fn into_foo(self) -> Foo;
}

impl IntoFoo for &str {
    fn into_foo(self) -> Foo {
        // Open the file                                      
        let mut file = BufReader::new(File::open(self).unwrap());

        // Dump the header     
        let mut header = String::new();
        let _ = file.read_line(&mut header);

        // Strip one more line
        let mut header_alt = String::new();
        let _ = file.read_line(&mut header_alt);

        // Read in the rest of the file line by line
        let mut data = Vec::new();         
        for (lineno,line) in file.lines().enumerate() {

            // Strip the error
            let line = line.unwrap();

            // Print some diagnostic information    
            println!("Line {}: val {}",lineno,line);

            // Save the element
            data.push(line.parse::<f64>().unwrap());
        }   

        Foo { file: self.to_string(), data }
    }
}

fn main() {

    // Read in our data from the file
    let foo = "foo.txt".into_foo(); 

    // Print out some debugging info
    println!("{:?}",foo); 
}
```

In this case, there's no need to worry about the ownership of the `BufReader` because it's created, used, and discarded in the same function. Of course, I don't fully know your use case, so this may not be suitable for your implementation.